# How to export a database app in Java to work properly

Tags: java, h2

A few weeks ago I put a question about "How to embedded a database into Java".
Thanks to you, I succeed to do that with H2 db. I made a simple app where you insert a Name and a Surname when the insert button is clicked and show the names and surnames in a JTextArea when the show button is pressed. In Eclipse, work perfectly, when the insert and show buttons are pressed.
Here is my problem:
I export the project, select Runnable JAR file etc. and when I start the app from the desktop and click on show button, the data from database are not displayed on JTextArea.
Why is this happening? 
Here is some part of code:

```
    static final String driver = "org.h2.Driver";
            static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:h2:lib/database";
            Connection conn = null;
    public void sql(){
                try{
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    System.out.println("Connect to my database");
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, "root", "#mysql");
                    System.out.println("Is connect");
                }catch(SQLException sql){
                    sql.printStackTrace();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
        }
class insertClass implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            try{
                String update = "INSERT INTO bazadedate.persoane(Name, Surname) values('"+ne.getText()+"', '"+se.getText()+"')";
                Statement st;
                st = conn.createStatement();
                st.executeUpdate(update);
            }catch(SQLException s){
                s.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    class showClass implements ActionListener{
        String name, surname;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
            try{
                String show = "SELECT * FROM bazadedate.persoane";
                Statement st;
                ResultSet rs;
                st = conn.createStatement();
                rs = st.executeQuery(show);
                while(rs.next()){
                    name = rs.getString("Name");
                    surname = rs.getString("Surname");
                    text.append(name + " " + surname + "\n");
                }
            }catch(SQLException s){
                s.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run your program with `java -jar YourJarFile.jar`, and see the errors displayed in the console.

Comment: I don't have errors and I select in the H2 Console Preferences, "Allow connection from other computers" and still don't work.

Comment: So, you're executing that code from another computer than the one where the database is located? The database URL doesn't say that it has to connect to another host. It reads the database from `lib/database`.

Comment: Also, are you sure `lib/database` exists _relative_ to your application?

Comment: Thanks you very much JB Nizet. I change in the jdbc url the address  in jdbc:h2:~/test and now it's work. It work because right now the database is on the server or why? If I send this app to another computer, will work? The data will be inserted?

Comment: Can anybody help me to solve my problem? I sended the app in another computer and the data are not displayed on the JTextArea, that means, the database aren't work properly...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `jdbc:h2:~/data/databaseName`. This is relative to the current user home directory. Or use `jdbc:h2:/data/databaseName`, which is an absolute path.

I suggest to avoid using a database URL of the form `jdbc:h2:lib/database`. In the very latest version of H2, this will actually not work and throw an exception. What the database URL means is that the database file is stored in the directory `lib` *relative* to the current working directory of the process. The current working directory is *usually* the place where you have started the application. If you use different applications (which are not in the same directory), then with this database URL you end up with different databases.

Comment: I made like you said and when I put the app on another computer still doesn't work. That means that the database can be accessed just from my computer, but all I want to do is to be accessed from other computers. 
Another user to be capable to insert a name and a surname to the "main database" via my interface, from another computer and when I accessing the database I want to view the inserted data by other user from another computer.

Comment: If you want to access a database that is stored in a different _computer_, then you should use the server mode. See the documentation for details. But that was not your original question.

Comment: Mr. Thomas Mueller, I want that.. a little tiny hint can you give me about it?

Comment: The documentation is [here](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes)